# How/when to calculate md5 hash of s3 uploads using Boto library

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

In the [boto/s3](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key) module there is function called `set_contents_from_filename` which seems to take an md5 hash as a parameter.

But the documentation is not clear on when/how to calculate the hash.  Could someone help me with this?  Also, how could I save the hash information to a file?

Answer (score 3):

The `set_contents_from_filename` method will automatically calculate the MD5 checksum for you.  There is an optional `md5` parameter to this method which allows you to pass in the MD5 if you have already calculated it for some reason in your application but if you don't pass a value in, boto will calculate it for you.

Comment: when i law the log file, this is what i have " DEBUG: Headers: {'x-amz-meta-host_name': 'xp-vm', 'Content-Length': '35250', 'Expect': '100-Continue', 'Content-MD5': 'dzci3KDIAPWMdzWDaBaaJg==', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'User-Agent': 'Boto/2.6.0-dev (win32)'}" . Is content-md5 the md5 value?.  for the same file in when i do md5 in console my value is "dde831f630d056bb79d7d236f52135ff"

Comment: That is the MD5 as calculated by boto.  By sending the MD5 in the request, it means that S3 can calculate the MD5 of what it receives and, if they don't match, S3 will return an error indicating that something was corrupted in the process.  This is an important integrity check.  I don't know why the MD5 seems to be different in the console. The only reason can be that the content itself is different for some reason.  I'm confident that boto's MD5 calculation is correct.

Answer (score 3):

As @garnatt already said, the `set_contents_from_filename` method will automatically calculate the MD5 checksum for you.

If you look at the docs, there is a method called `compute_md5` which returns a tuple containing the MD5 checksum in a hexdigest (what your getting in the console using `md5sum`) and also base64 encoded which it sends to Amazon which is what your seeing in the headers.

The `md5` parameter in the `set_contents_from_filename` method takes the MD5 checksum in a tuple format, the same way `compute_md5` returns. If you need to calculate it manually, the best way is to use the `compute_md5` method. Otherwise you have to build a tuple in the correct format before passing it to the `md5` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The MD5 calculate by boto is the base 64 encode of checksum. The 'Content-MD5' in header for a given file to be uploaded/already uploaded can be calculated by:

```
import hashlib, base64
conn = S3Connection(access_key, secret_key)
bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket_name')
#If you want to calculate MD5 of a file already uploaded
obj_key = bucket.get_key('file_name_in_s3')
content = obj_key.get_contents_as_string()
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(content)
value = m.digest()
remote_md5 = base64.b64encode(value)

#To calculate md5 of a file to be uploaded to S3
cur_md5 = base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5(open('Local/Path/To/File').read()).digest())
```